# Use SharePoint Online in applications that rely on local data

Tags: sharepoint-online

Thanks to SharePoint Online, I am about to get rid of my file server.

Now I wonder if I could use SharePoint Online with some of our applications running on our Windows Servers 2019.
Those applications rely on data available locally on those servers.
The data is located on the D: drive of each server so I could easily point to a SharePoint Online shared document location instead.

But what will happen when I log off from the server?
The application(s) will continue to use and modify those files.
Can I force the sync to continue with SharePoint Online even I am not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

The content in SPO is all directly stored in Microsoft's server, and the application in the local server will not affect the use of SPO. But if you just set a link to a file in the local server in the SPO, it will have an impact after you log out of the local server.

I would recommend that you store your files in SPO instead of just setting up a link.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear

Each business application has its own Windows Server 2019 and the data used by the app is located on the D: drive

Comment: I also use the “Configure team site libraries to sync automatically” policy to display each SharePoint Online Documents in File Explorer (we have few of them) when necessary.

Comment: I could create a new SharePoint Online specific for the application and instead of having my data located on the D: drive, I could have it on this new SharePoint Online Documents and point the application to it.

Comment: As long as I am logged in, I believe that the scenario above would work but I fear that as soon as I log off, issues might start.